# Enabling Logging for JpaTransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using JpaTransactionManager with hibernate 3 inside spring 3.5 container. I am not able to enable logging for JPA. I wish to see the logs for transaction management for debugging some of my services. I am using log4j.

Here is what I have in my log4j.properties

```
# For JPA
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\apps\application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file
```

Comment: What if you simply enable `org.springframework=DEBUG`? You'll find then which loggers are interesting (between tons of others).

Comment: Thanks, I moved to logging using logback (http://logback.qos.ch/) on top of SLF4J, and now everything works smoothly. I think previously there were some issues with SLF4J as I was using it in NOOP mode.

Comment: Would you mind answering the question yourself then, so that you we can have it marked as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me in terms of enabling logging for JPATransactionManager:
1. Download logback jars (logback-classic-1.0.1.jar, logback-core-1.0.1.jar) and put in classpath. Since I am using SLF4J, I also have log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar.
2. Use following logback.xml (in WEB-INF/classes) for configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.home}/logs/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ALL</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" level="DEBUG"/>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Transaction logging can specifically be set in `log4j.properties` by:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=DEBUG
```

Other logs of interest in this context:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Comment: if I move to log4j2. how can I convert to log4j2?