# Spring Transaction management - How to know the API is executed in one transaction or not?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

How to know if my particular flow or API is getting executed in one transaction or not ?

I am using the JPATransactionManager

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
```

I am using @Transactional annotation at API to declare the transactional boundaries.

I am trying hard to find out clear transaction boundaries in my application and know when particular transaction is getting started, when particular transaction is ended.. I also tried logs for JPATranscationManager at Trace level but didn't help much.

Comment: Try to use log4j as in this post [Enabling Logging for JpaTransactionManager][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172787/enabling-logging-for-jpatransactionmanager